# Cannot remove automatically applied coupon, are there alternative ways?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am automatically adding a coupon for specific products which works fine, however this prevents me from being able to remove the coupon and I can't add a different one. I get an AJAX response back saying the coupon was added or removed but it doesn't actually do anything.

If I comment this code out, the adding/removing of coupons works fine.

I am trying to remove the coupon via AJAX, is there anything to lookout for that might prevent this from functioning correctly? It looks like as soon as a coupon is added it removes it again.

[image]

Which I believe is due to the below code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'auto_apply_coupons' );
function auto_apply_coupons() {

    $coupon_code = 'test25';

    $autoCoupon = array( 1, 2 );

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        ...


        if ($cart_item['type'] === 'Subscription') {
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $autoCoupon ) ) {
                WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a different way that I can automatically apply a coupon whilst still being able to add/remove new/existing coupons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by switching to a different action, I now trigger my automatic coupon logic using the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'auto_apply_coupons' );
```